# AttributeError: module 'pyqtgraph.Qt.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'."

Tags: linux, pyqtgraph, qtgui, qapplication

Details about my system;

Ubunttu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64

pyqtgraph v0.13.1

pyhton v3.10

[The code I'm trying to run on line 56](https://github.com/habom2310/Heart-rate-measurement-using-camera/blob/master/new_update/test_signal_processing.py);

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
```

The Error I get;

```
AttributeError: module 'pyqtgraph.Qt.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'.
```

is QApplication no longer supported in pyqtgraph?

Not sure on what to do, I got this source code from [github](https://github.com/habom2310/Heart-rate-measurement-using-camera/blob/master/new_update/test_signal_processing.py) and I don't completely understand what the author was doing.

Edit:

I get a similar error on line 58.

```
win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="plotting")
AttributeError: module 'pyqtgraph' has no attribute 'GraphicsWindow'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this is how I resolved mine.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets  
import pyqtgraph as pg
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
```

Answer (score 0):

`GraphicsWindow` has been deprecated, you should replace it with `GraphicsLayoutWidget`.